# Azure DevOps YAML build pipeline - Set script task name

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a YAML build pipeline with a simple script task that sets the build configuration based on the branch being built:

```
- script: |
    echo Current branch is %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME%
    if %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME% == "master" (
        SET BUILD_CONFIG=Release
    ) else (
        SET BUILD_CONFIG=Debug
    )
    echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration]%BUILD_CONFIG%
    echo BuildConfiguration set to '%BUILD_CONFIG%'
```

This works fine but the task appears in the list as 'CmdLine' and I'd like something a little more descriptive.
The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in the MS documentation indicates that I should be able to add a displayName entry to the end:

```
- script: |
    echo Current branch is %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME%
    if %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME% == "master" (
        SET BUILD_CONFIG=Release
    ) else (
        SET BUILD_CONFIG=Debug
    )
    echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration]%BUILD_CONFIG%
    echo BuildConfiguration set to '%BUILD_CONFIG%'
    displayName: 'Determine Build Configuration'
```

However, this fails with `'displayName:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Such a simple thing but I've tried everything I can think of and just can't get it to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix indentation:

```
- script: |
    echo Current branch is %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME%
    if %BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME% == "master" (
        SET BUILD_CONFIG=Release
    ) else (
        SET BUILD_CONFIG=Debug
    )
    echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration]%BUILD_CONFIG%
    echo BuildConfiguration set to '%BUILD_CONFIG%'
  displayName: 'Determine Build Configuration'
```